# how to close kivy pop from another class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy

python file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MainPage(FloatLayout):
    con = ObjectProperty(None)
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(MainPage,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def openme(self):
        Pops().open()

    def openpop(self):
        con = Pops2()
        con.content = Content()
        con.open()

class Pops(Popup):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Pops,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()

class Pops2(Popup):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Pops2,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()

class Content(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Content,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        pass

    def closepops2(self):
        Pops2().dismiss()

class PopCheck(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('PopCheck.kv')
        return MainPage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopCheck().run()
```

kv file:

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<MainPage>:
    Button:
        text: 'Open pop1'
        pos_hint:{'x': .1,'top': .2}
        size_hint:(.1,.1)
        on_press: root.openme()
    Button:
        text: 'Open pop2'
        pos_hint:{'x': .75,'top': .2}
        size_hint:(.1,.1)
        on_press: root.openpop()




<Pops>:
    title: 'Content within the popup is displaying twice under kivy1.10.1 with python3.x'
    id: pop
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 220
    auto_dismiss: True
    #height: container.height
    separator_color: 255,0,0,0.9

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.size
        id: container

        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            cols: 1
            TextInput:
                id: usr
                hint_text: 'User Name'
                multiline: False
                write_tab:False
                text: 'sri'
                markup: True
                on_text: root.focus_on()


            TextInput:
                id: psd
                multiline: False
                write_tab:False
                hint_text:'Password'
                password: True
                text: 'sri'
                #input_filter: 'int'
                on_text: root.focus_on()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 45
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                background_color: 255,0,0,0.9
                on_press: root.closeme()

            Button:
                text: 'Login'
                background_color: 0,1,255,0.7

        Label:
            id: er
            foreground_color: 1, 250, 100, 1
            color: 1, 0.67, 0, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 0
            text:''
            font_size: '12pt'

<Pops2>:
    title: 'Content from seperate Class but no close option'
    size_hint: .75,.50
    auto_dismiss: True
    #height: container.height
    separator_color: 255,0,0,0.9

<Content>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos: self.pos
    size: root.size

    TextInput:
        id: vehno
        hint_text:'Name'
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False
    TextInput:
        id: stopnam
        hint_text: 'Roll No'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False
    TextInput:
        id: descr
        hint_text: 'Department'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False

    TextInput:
        id: descr
        hint_text: 'Year'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False




    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        on_press: root.closepops2()#Factory.Pops2().dismiss()
```

Comment: read [ask].....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

Close the second Popup by inovking `closeme()` method in `class Pops2()`. Please refer to example for details.

### kv file

1. Remove *import* statement for *Factory*
2. Replace `root.closepops2()` with `app.root.con.closeme()`

### Python File

1. Replace `con` with `self.con` in method `openpop()`
2. If there no other codes beside `super(...)` and `pass` in the constructor then remove all constructors.

## Example

### main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.11.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty


class MainPage(FloatLayout):
    con = ObjectProperty(None)

    def openme(self):
        Pops().open()

    def openpop(self):
        self.con = Pops2()
        self.con.content = Content()
        self.con.open()


class Pops(Popup):

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()


class Pops2(Popup):

    def closeme(self):
        self.dismiss()


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class PopCheck(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('PopCheck.kv')
        return MainPage()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    PopCheck().run()
```

### PopCheck.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<MainPage>:
    Button:
        text: 'Open pop1'
        pos_hint:{'x': .1,'top': .2}
        size_hint:(.1,.1)
        on_press: root.openme()
    Button:
        text: 'Open pop2'
        pos_hint:{'x': .75,'top': .2}
        size_hint:(.1,.1)
        on_press: root.openpop()

<Pops>:
    title: 'Content within the popup is displaying twice under kivy1.10.1 with python3.x'
    id: pop
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 400, 220
    auto_dismiss: True
    #height: container.height
    separator_color: 255,0,0,0.9

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        pos: self.pos
        size: root.size
        id: container

        GridLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            cols: 1
            TextInput:
                id: usr
                hint_text: 'User Name'
                multiline: False
                write_tab:False
                text: 'sri'
                markup: True
                on_text: root.focus_on()


            TextInput:
                id: psd
                multiline: False
                write_tab:False
                hint_text:'Password'
                password: True
                text: 'sri'
                #input_filter: 'int'
                on_text: root.focus_on()

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 45
            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                background_color: 255,0,0,0.9
                on_press: root.closeme()

            Button:
                text: 'Login'
                background_color: 0,1,255,0.7

        Label:
            id: er
            foreground_color: 1, 250, 100, 1
            color: 1, 0.67, 0, 1
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 0
            text:''
            font_size: '12pt'

<Pops2>:
    title: 'Content from seperate Class but no close option'
    size_hint: .75,.50
    auto_dismiss: True
    #height: container.height
    separator_color: 255,0,0,0.9

<Content>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    pos: self.pos
    size: root.size

    TextInput:
        id: vehno
        hint_text:'Name'
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False
    TextInput:
        id: stopnam
        hint_text: 'Roll No'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False
    TextInput:
        id: descr
        hint_text: 'Department'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False

    TextInput:
        id: descr
        hint_text: 'Year'
        allow_copy: False
        password: True
        multiline: False
        write_tab: False

    Button:
        text: 'Close'
        on_press:
            app.root.con.closeme()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Popup 2]
[image: Img02 - Popup 2 Closed]

Comment: Thank you so much! You made my day! How did you compiled this program in python 3.x and kivy1.11.1 without error "Popup can have only one widget as content" ?

Comment: Nothing special. Ran it using Python 3.6.5, Kivy 1.11.0-dev0 and Xubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver via PyCharm and at command prompt without any error.

Comment: In python2.x and kivy 1.9.1 this program executed nicely but in python3.x and kivy1.10.1dev popup's content is displaying twice and thats the problem! If i frame nested layout under boxlayout for the content it throws the error "Popup can have only one widget as content".

Comment: What is your OS i.e. Windows 10/8, Mac OS, etc.?

Comment: python 2.x and kivy1.9.1 on Ubuntu 17.04